# Linked list segmentation fault in terminal, but not in debugger

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I wrote a function that appends a value to the end of a linked list made up of val and next. However, I keep getting the error: Segmentation Fault 11: core dumped. When I run this on gdb, though, I do not get any errors. Any thoughts?

```
intlist* intlist_append(intlist* xs, int val) 
{
    intlist* new = (intlist*)malloc(sizeof(intlist*));
    new->val = val;
    new->next = NULL;
    intlist* ys = xs;
    while(ys->next) 
    {
        ys = ys->next;
    }
    ys->next = new;
    free(new);
    return xs;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(intlist*)` --> `sizeof(intlist)` or `sizeof(*new)`, Also `free(new);` remove this.

Comment: hm, I suppose I don't understand how the asterisks work here. Can you give me a quick explanation? Also, thank you.

Comment: `intlist*` is pointer. You need size of `intlist`, not pointer size.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am still getting the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY But aren't I making a pointer?

Comment: _still getting the same error._ It seems that there is a problem with other parts of the code. E.g `xs` is `NULL`. etc.

Comment: Did you get rid of the line: `free(new)`?

Comment: Why are you returning xs?  It is sent as a reference.  There is no need to return xs.

Comment: @bruceg Yes, but shouldn't you free everything you malloc after it has been used?

Comment: @Nguaial the function returns a pointer to an intlist. What else should I return?

Comment: @JerseyFonseca you should free the memory when you are done with it, but in this case you're not done with it.  You just assigned the memory that `new` points at into the `ys-next` pointer.  So, they both point to the same memory location.  So, if you freed `new` then `ys->next` points to unallocated memory.

Comment: @JerseyFonseca - It should be void.  The changes are already taken place at the memory level since xs is sent in as an address. There is no need for the function to return.

Answer (score 1):

This part of the function

```
    // ...
    intlist* ys = xs;
    while(ys->next) 
    {
        ys = ys->next;
    }
    ys->next = new;
    free(new);
    return xs;
}
```

is wrong. First of all `xs` can be equal to `NULL`. In this case using the expression `ys->next` results in undefined behavior.

Secondly you shall not free the node `new`. Otherwise the function does not make sense.

Thirdly, the head stored in the local variable `ys` can be changed. However the value of `xs` will not be changed. In this case the function returns the unchanged value of the variable `xs`.

Also the first statement of the function is also wrong

```
intlist* new = (intlist*)malloc(sizeof(intlist*));
                                       ^^^^^^^^
```

There shall be

```
intlist* new = (intlist*)malloc(sizeof(intlist));
                                       ^^^^^^^
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
intlist * intlist_append( intlist *xs, int val ) 
{
    intlist *new_node = malloc( sizeof( intlist ) );

    if ( new_node != NULL )
    {
        new_node->val  = val;
        new_node->next = NULL;

        intlist **current = &xs;

        while ( *current ) current = &( *current )->next; 

        *current = new_node;
    }

    return xs;
}
```

Comment: I don't think the function  needs to return anything.  The changes are taken place at the memory level.

Comment: @Nguaial In this case the function will be wrong when the head is changed because the parameter is a local variable of the function.